# is there anyway to highlight parts of image maps

Tags: jquery, html, image, imagemap

i have an image and i am using an imagemap so i have links over certain parts of the image (.png file).  Is there anyway to also have the section "light up" or get highlighted when i move my mouse over that part of the image using jquery or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out :
[jQuery plugin for map](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/maphilight)

Answer (score 1):

There's [mapper.js](http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/), which is very very powerful. Just look at those demos.

If it's a jQuery plugin you're looking for, there's [maphilight](http://davidlynch.org/blog/2008/03/maphilight-image-map-mouseover-highlighting/).